# Why do lsusb and lspci command not show touchscreen device?

Tags: touchpad, lsusb, lspci, i2c

Ubuntu 20.04

My laptop has touchscreen device which enables touching function. I can view its info by command `less /proc/bus/input/devices`. It looks like:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=1a1b Version=0100
N: Name="06CB:00 06CB:1A1B"
P: Phys=i2c-06CB:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-06CB:00/0018:06CB:1A1B.0002/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event6
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

I can view the touching event log by `sudo cat /dev/input/event6`.
So I can believe my ubuntu 20.04 has well support about touch-screen. And I expect `lsusb` should includes the touch-screen device info. But it doesn't. The output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56f2 IMC Networks USB camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Do I mis-understand something? Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I tried `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02ab
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

It seems that no touch screen device included. Any further suggestion please? Thanks~

Comment: The first result indicates a PCI device, not USB. So, try `lspci` instead.

Comment: So what is the real problem? Does the touchscreen work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `lsusb` or `lspci` don't show the touchpad is that the device is not connected directly to USB or PCI. It is connected to `i2c` bus.

You can see it in `Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-06CB:00/0018:06CB:1A1B.0002/input/input14`

The `i2c` controller is connected to the PCI bus and you can see it too.

```
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
```